# JFrame flash image for 1/100 second

Tags: java, image, swing

I have JFrame and need to flash an Image for 10 milliseconds (or the minimum the monitor can support).

Currently, this is what I have done:

I have a **JFrame** with a **JPanel** with overwritten `paintComponent()` method. When I need to flash that image, I call the `repaint()` method to draw the image on the **JFrame**, then schedule a next to call `repaint()` again to remove the image after 10 milliseconds. However it makes a long flash, that is very visible to bare eye.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean show = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    f.setFocusable(false);
    JPanel c = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (show) {
                try {
                    // I was too lazy to save the image as a variable ;)
                    g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Puppy.png")), 1, 1, null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    };
    c.setOpaque(false);
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    f.getContentPane().add(c);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(f, false);

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            show = true;
            f.repaint();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    show = false;
                    f.repaint();
                    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time + Boolean.toString(show));
                }
            }, 10);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

***Question: Why is the frame flashing for so long, and not for 10 milliseconds?***

Comment: Don't know what operating system you're using, but some operating systems interpret "10ms" more literally than others.  You shouldn't rely on anything using `Thread.sleep()` or `TimerTask` to measure times particularly accurately.

Comment: Consider using a Swing `Timer` instead.  Also, when showing a window on the screen, it can take time BEFORE the window is actually shown, which could mean that you've "hidden" the image before the window is even on the screen...

Comment: There are also delays in establishing the `Timer`, Event Dispatching Thread and the time between requesting a repaint and that repaint actually taking place...

Comment: But the system.out.println() is printing a value around 1000000. It does everything in time. How can I avoid this delay?

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: **Never** read in an image within a paintComponent method or do anything that takes time to perform in that method. That method needs to be as fast as possible, else your program will be perceived as lagging. Also, why would you want to re-read the image in many times rather than simply reading it in once, and then displaying it in paintComponent as many times as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many things that might be occuring...

- The time between calling `setVisible` and the time that the frame is actually visible to the user...
- The time to setup the Event Dispatching Thread...
- The time to setup the `Timer` and schedule the `TimerTask`
- The time between making a request for the frame to be repainted and when the repaint actually occurs
- The fact that you are requesting the frame to be repainted and not the component which is actually displaying the image
- Some other activity on the system, both within the Java API and/or the OS...

You need to try and mitigate some of these issues...

So, instead of scheduling the `TimerTask` straight after calling `setVisible`, may be use a `WindowListener` so you can be notified when the window is opened and start the timer then...

Instead of building everything within the thread that calls `main`, make sure you are creating and updating the UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Instead of calling `repaint` on the frame, try repainting the actual component you want repainted...

Instead of using `java.util.Timer`, use a `javax.swing.Timer`, it's safer when making modifications to the state of the UI

The following example simply uses a `JLabel` to render the image and removes it after the `javax.swing.Timer` ticks...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

/**
 *
 * @author shane
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\_MTCGAC__Pulling_Cords_by_Dispozition.png"));
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                            Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    frame.remove(label);
                                    frame.revalidate();
                                    frame.repaint();
                                }
                            });
                            timer.setRepeats(false);
                            timer.start();
                        }
                    });
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(label);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. It still flashes the frame for so long, and not for the specified time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can fix it.  What OS are you using?  What image are you using?

Comment: So three things come to find.  Java and Windows might not be able to manage a 10ms delay, it might just be too short; You could convert the image to a compatible color model, which would make it paint faster; make sure you re-load the image BEFORE you paint it. In my tests, I either got a very quick flash, or a blank screen (Windows 7)